# Remove spaces after file extensions in txt file

Tags: windows-10, script, powershell-5.0

I need to remove from my List.txt, everything after the file extension, keeping the extension.

I tried unsuccessfully to use the commands in the links:
[how-to-use-powershell-to-remove-space-from-the-end-of-a-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579157/how-to-use-powershell-to-remove-space-from-the-end-of-a-line-in-a-text-file)
[powershell-trim-remove-all-characters-after-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089516/powershell-trim-remove-all-characters-after-a-string)

List:

```
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3                                   -9,6
06 - Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).flac         -9,1
08 - Kool & The Gang - Get Down On It (Soul Funk House Remix).wav                               -10,7
```

What I need:

```
05 - Earth Wind and Fire - September (The Reflex Revision).mp3  
06 - Electric Light Orchestra - Last Train To London (Bootleg Extended Dance Remix).flac
08 - Kool & The Gang - Get Down On It (Soul Funk House Remix).wav
```

I tried the command, but without success:

```
$content = Get-Content $files
$content | Foreach {$_.Substring(0, $_.IndexOf('.mp3', '.flac', '.wav' ))} | Set-Content $files
```

How to remove after file extension, keeping extensions?

Comment: If the first number in the pair at the end of each line is always negative, your ForEach script block can be: `$_ -replace '\s+\-\d+,\d+$'`. If not all the initial numbers are negative, use `$_ -replace '\s+\-?\d+,\d+$'`. The regex captures "<WhiteSpace><MinusSign><OneOrMoreDigits><Comma><OneOrMoreDigits>".

Comment: @Keith Miller It worked perfectly... please put it as an answer so I can vote for it ok?... Thanks.

Comment: Will do........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your sample data, it looks like the easiest approach would be to match the most consistent portion of each string, the whitespace and numbers following the filename:

- `<WhiteSpace><MinusSign><OneOrMoreDigits><Comma><OneOrMoreDigits>`

using a [regular expression](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html):

- `'\s+\-\d+,\d+$'`

with the [`-Replace`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-operator) operator, which will simply remove the matching text if no replacement string is specified:

```
    { $_ -replace '\s+\-\d+,\d+$' }
```

If the minus sign is optional, follow it with the `One or none (?)` quantifier:

```
    $_ -replace '\s+\-?\d+,\d+$'
```

Comment: I need some help... the script was made to be called within a batch file, when I run the script directly on the desktop, everything works ok, but when I run it via batch, the txt file it creates cuts the song names longer than 102 characters. Your remove command removes spaces up to the limit of the song with the most characters, the smaller songs are left with blank spaces up to the limit of the biggest song! Why does it not work when called via batch?

Comment: No clue offhand -- never done much with batch. But edit your question summarizing the current problem and including the relevant batch code and I'll take a look -- or maybe someone else can help.

Comment: I posted a question titled `Run powershell script, as administrator, via batch file with parameter passing.` As you suggested. Note: One of the problems I found was that it was necessary to run the script as an administrator, when it is called via batch file, ok?

Comment: Good to hear. Will check out the question & answer. Is it related to the permissions on the directories? Were you logged into an account with admin privileges when you tested at the console?

Comment: Keith I only have one user account on my computer and the profile is admin. Only I use the computer.